# Dynamically setting and getting bean properties in XPages

Tags: java, xpages, javabeans, el

Just another Java problem (I'm a noob, I know): is it possible to use dynamic property binding in a Custom Control with a dynamic property getter in a Java bean?

I'll explain. I use this feature extensively in my Custom Controls:

```
            <xp:inputTextarea id="DF_TiersM">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName]}]]></xp:this.value>
```

This is used in a control where both datasource and the name of the field are passed as parameters. This works, so far so good.
Now, in some cases, the datasource is a managed bean. When the above lines are interpreted, apparently code is generated to get or set the value of ... something. But what exactly?

I get this error: *Error getting property 'SomeField' from bean of type com.sjef.AnyRecord* which I guess is correct for there is no public getSomeField() in my bean. All properties are defined dynamically in the bean.

So how can I make XPages read the properties? Is there a universal getter (and setter) that allows me to use the name of a property as a parameter instead of the inclusion in a fixed method name? If XPages doesn't find getSomeField(), will it try something else instead, e.g. just get(String name) or so?

As always: I really appreciate your help and answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the binding works depends on whether or not your Java object implements a supported interface. If it doesn't (if it's just some random Java object), then any properties are treated as "bean-style" names, so that, if you want to call ".getSomeField()", then the binding would be like "#{obj.someField}" (or "#{obj['someField']}", or so forth).

If you want it to fall back to a common method, that's a job for either the `DataObject` or `Map` interfaces - `Map` is larger to implement, but is more standard (and you could inherit from `AbstractMap` if applicable), while `DataObject` is basically an XPages-ism but one I'm a big fan of (for reference, document data sources are `DataObject`s). Be warned, though: if you implement one of those, EL will *only* bind to the `get` or `getValue` method and will ignore normal setters and getters. If you want to use those when present, you'll have to write reflection code to do that (I recommend using Apache BeanUtils).

I have a post describing this in more detail on my blog: https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/expanding-your-use-of-el-%28part-1%29

Comment: Hi, and thanks! I don't really want XPages to call ".getSomeField()", instead I need ".get('SomeField')" or so. I use a dynamic custom control with multiple types of data sources, and one of them happens to be a bean. The bean should be able to support properties with names that are unknown at compile-time...

Comment: Yep, then a `Map` or `DataObject` is what you want. Here's an example `DataObject` that gets its data from a translation bundle (but it could be anywhere): https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/FE0AE00B7CEC4F8885257D46006CAB68

Comment: Excellent! I'd never have found the DataObject class. Thanks for the example!